# JMenu is not visible

Tags: java, swing, button

I have a JMenu and JPanel inside my JFrame

Setup Code:

```
public Gui(String title) {
    super(title);

    createGUIComponents();
    pack();

    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(180, 100));
    this.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void createGUIComponents() {
    Container c = this.getContentPane();

    JPanel panel = new SpecialJPanel();

    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File", false);
    fileMenu.add("New");
    fileMenu.add("Open");
    fileMenu.add("Save");
    fileMenu.add("Save As");

    c.add(panel, "Center");
    c.add(menu, "Center");
}
```

Whenever I click the File menu button on the JMenuBar, nothing shows up. I think it's being blocked by the JPanel, which is being constantly updated. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `I think it's being blocked by the JPanel, which is being constantly updated` - then maybe you should post a proper SSCCE so we can see what you are doing. If you think this is the problem, then stop the updating and see what happens. `c.add(panel, "Center");` - Don't use a String literal for the constraint. Use the proper static variable found in the BorderLayout class.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add menu to the menuBar, so add this line:

```
menu.add(fileMenu);
```

Also, instead `c.add(menu)`, you should use

```
setJMenuBar(menu);
```

Comment: It still doesn't show up, but thanks for pointing that out. Also, it should be this.setJMenuBar(menu)

Comment: @JakeSumrican, the "this" is not required.

Comment: +1 for ignoring what the OP was trying to do, and instead showing an altogether better approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. The standard layout of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`
2. `BorderLayout` offers 5 areas which can each accept ***1*** component.

So wherreas the code reads:

```
c.add(panel, "Center");
c.add(menu, "Center");
```

It should actually read something more like:

```
c.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Don't use magic numbers!
c.add(menu, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

---

Having said that, a `JFrame` has a better way to show a `JMenuBar`, detailed in the [answer by @CoderTitan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16269954/418556).

Comment: I've tried this, but It just briefly displays before disappearing. The actual menu button stays selected though, so how would you allow the menu to display over it?